# Converting an object into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript object in the format

```
{
    "header": {
        "dataFields": ["number", "name", "quantity", "id", "from"]
    },
    "data": [
        "20|sam|12|2|2012-06-29T00:00Z|",
        "18|peter|231|12|",
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get it in to this format:

```
[{"number" : "20", "name":"sam", "quantity" : "12", "id":"2"},
 {"number" : "18", "name":"peter", "quantity": "231", "id" 12"}]
```

I dont want the field "from in the output array.. what could be the best way to acheive it??

```
var l={};

for ( var key in responseData.positions[i]){
    l.name=key;
        for(var k=0; k<responseData.positions.length;k++){
            for ( var key in responseData.positions[k]) {
                l.value= responseData.positions[k][key] ;
            }
        }
mainArray.push(l);
```

Comment: So is this about JSON or JavaScript? Even if you get the original data as JSON, once you parsed it into native data types, it has nothing to do with JSON anymore. I actually assume you are having an object and want to convert it into an array of objects.

Comment: @Barmar IVe added what Ive tried in to the question

Comment: Your code doesn't bear any resemblance to the data structure. I assume `responseData` contains the object, but what is `positions`? Why aren't you using `responseData.header` or `responseData.data`? Where are you setting `i`? And your braces don't match, you have 3 opens and only 2 closes.

Comment: responseData.positions is the input array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the array map method to iterate through the data array and convert it.

Code and live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N9QyQ/

```
var object={
"header": {
    "dataFields": ["number", "name", "quantity", "id", "rom"]
},
"data": [
    "20|sam|12|2|2012-06-29T00:00Z",
    "18|peter|231|12|"
 ]
} ;
var result=object.data.map(function(string){
    var split=string.split("|"), item={};
    for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
        item[object.header.dataFields[i]]=split[i];
    }
    return item;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mainArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < responseData.positions.data.length; i++) {
    var dataArray = responseData.positions.data[i].split("|");
    var newObject = {};
    for (j = 0; j < responseData.positions.header.length; j++) {
        if (responseData.positions.header[j] != "from") {
            newObject[responseData.positions.header[j]] = dataArray[j];
        }
    }
    mainArray.push(newObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    "header": {
        "dataFields": ["number", "name", "quantity", "id", "from"]
    },
    "data": [
        "20|sam|12|2|2012-06-29T00:00Z|",
        "18|peter|231|12|"
    ]
};
var result = [];
for(var i = 0, headers = obj.header.dataFields, len = obj.data.length, hLen = headers.length; i < len; i++) {
    var split = obj.data[i].split("|");
    var entry = {};
    // assuming you want first four elements
    /*
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        entry[headers[j]] = split[j];
    }
    */
    // assuming you want to exclude from field
    for(var j = 0; j < hLen; j++) {
        if(headers[j] == "from")
            continue;
        entry[headers[j]] = split[j];
    }       
    result.push(entry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery you could do the following

```
jsonData = {
    "header": {
        "dataFields": ["number", "name", "quantity", "id", "from"]
    },
    "data": [
        "20|sam|12|2|2012-06-29T00:00Z|",
        "18|peter|231|12|",
    ]
};


tmpData = {}
newData = []

$.each(jsonData['data'], function () {
    data = this;
    $.each(jsonData['header']['dataFields'], function (index, header) {
        if (header !== "from") {
            tmpData[header] = data.split('|')[index]
        }
    });
    newData.push(tmpData);
    tmpData = {};
});
```

`newData` will contain

```
[
    {id: "2", name: "sam",number: "20",quantity: "12"},
    { id: "12", name: "peter", number: "18", quantity: "231" }
]
```

You can check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gfGXF/)

Comment: The map method I mentioned in my answer also exists in jQuery ($.map)

Comment: sorry, I wasnt trying to undermine your answer. I had written this answer a while back but forgot to post it

Comment: no worries :-) I was just commenting your code and pointing to a shorter method.